# Declaring a variable of a variable?

Tags: c++, directx

I'm working on using input from the mouse to move a sprite in DirectX.

I'm trying to use this example from the professor, But you see my commented error:

```cpp
// Mouse
float mouseSensitivity = 2000.0f;
spriteObj[5].position.x += (mouseState.lX * mouseSensitivity) * dt;//Error  1   error C2228: left of '.position' must have class/struct/union   //Error 2   error C2228: left of '.x' must have class/struct/union
```

I am trying to initialize the variables position and x of "spriteObj[5].position.x", But How to I declare x as a member of position as a member of spriteObj[5]?

Comment: What's `spriteObj`? Btw the error says it all: `spriteObj[5]` is not a class, struct or union.

Comment: I have to say DirectX is not a very nice way to learn C++.

Comment: The error says `spriteObj[5]` is not a `struct`/`class`/`union`, so can't have a `.position` member; most often, that error happens when `spriteObj[5]` is a *pointer* to some `struct` / `class`, and you just need to code `spriteObj[5]->position.x` instead.  If could also be something completely unrelated to `struct`s / `class`es - in which case you need to rethink things....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I left some a bleak, undetailed question here. Solving it made me feel pretty dumb, lol. The error really did explain it all, I had initialized no struct to hold the position data. Here is the finished struct that solved the issue.

```css
struct SpriteObject
{
D3DXVECTOR3 position;
// Translation
float rotation;
// Z rotation
float scale;
// Uniform scaling (x and y value the same)
D3DCOLOR color;
// Color modulation
};
```